# rails3 show not getting :user_id in one case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I have a strange problem.  I've been coding in Rails for, off and on, a year.  I created a new project recently and used scaffolding.  Things were going fine, yesturday I started implementing some favoriting features.  Now I have a strange problem.  I rolled back the stuff I did last night but still have the problem.  First

```
 Entry belongs to user
 User has many entries
```

My Entry show method in my controller is very standard and simple

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @entry = @user.entries.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
   format.html # show.html.erb
   format.json { render :json => @entry }
  end
end
```

When I view the entry from a normal link in the entries index

```
<%= link_to 'Show', user_entry_path(@user, entry) %>
```

I takes me to where it should go:

```
/users/4/entries/11
```

When I create new things still look good

```
/users/4/entries/new
```

Until I click "create entry" or the submit button

```
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

Then it goes to

```
/entries/20  ...with the error:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in EntriesController#show
Couldn't find User without an ID
```

If I go back to the entries index however, the file new entry is there and the show link takes me to the right place.  Thoughts?  Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you that `User.find(params[:user_id])` couldn't find a user with that ID. Try checking the structure of the GET parameters in the server logs.

If your GET path is `/entries/20`, then the path only has an entry ID and is missing a user ID. You might be able to fix this in your `Controller#create` by having it redirect to `user_entry_path` instead of `entry_path`.

Comment: For others:
format.html { redirect_to [@user, @entry], :notice => 'Entry was successfully created.' }

Answer (score 1):

How does your form look like?
I think you have nested routes? Your form should look like following:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @entry] do |f| %>
  <% # your fields %>
<% end %>
```

Your form seems to point to resources entry, instead of the nested ressource..

Comment: My form:  <%= form_for([@user, @entry]) do |f| %> ... it does make the correct association if I navigate to the entry index page, i see the new entry and then when i click show, it shows it as an associated route.  It's only when i submit the new form that it doesn't go to the associated route... thx

Comment: Take a look in the generated html code where the action points to..should be /users/id/entries

Comment: It says <input type="submit" value="Create Entry" name="commit">